# how to rewrite callback hell into promise?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

my callback hell route works fine...

```
var myCallbackHell = router.route('/');
myCallbackHell.get(function(req, res, next) {
  bookModel.find({title: "Animal Farm"}).then(function(book) {
    movieModel.find({title: "Intouchables"}).then(function(movie) {
      gameModel.find({title: "The Last of Us"}).then(function(game) {
        res.render('index', {book_found: book, movie_found: movie, game_found: game});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

however I would like to use promise. Any help, hint?

Comment: More than callback hell your code looks like a promise hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and write the same, like this

```
var promises = [
  bookModel.find({title: "Animal Farm"}),
  movieModel.find({title: "Intouchables"}),
  gameModel.find({title: "The Last of Us"})
];

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
  res.render('index', {book_found: values[0], movie_found: values[1], game_found: values[2]});
}).catch(function(err) {
  // deal with err
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2017 have the async/await syntax

> To prevent Promise hell

```
var myCallbackHell = router.route('/');
myCallbackHell.get( async function(req, res, next) {
    var book = await bookModel.find({title: "Animal Farm"})
    var movie = await movieModel.find({title: "Intouchables"})
    var game = await gameModel.find({title: "The Last of Us"})

    res.render('index', {book_found: book, movie_found: movie, game_found: game});
})
```

You should catch the errors and rejects, so for that:

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        var book = await bookModel.find({title: "Animal Farm"})
        var movie = await movieModel.find({title: "Intouchables"})
        var game = await gameModel.find({title: "The Last of Us"})

        res.render('index', {book_found: book, movie_found: movie, game_found: game}) 

    } catch (e) { next(e) }
})
```